# string not recognized? C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed

Tags: c++

I have this class defined but it doesn't work at all.

```
#ifndef LIBROS_H
#define LIBROS_H
#include "Articulo.h"
class Libros: public Articulo
{
public:
Libros();
~Libros();
string Autor;
string Editorial;
void mostrar();
void llenar();
};
# endif
```

this gives:
error
C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note:C++ does not support default-int

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to `#include` the right header.

```
#include <string>
```

And since you have no `using` statement, you'll need to qualify your `strings` with the namespace they're in, which is `std`:

```
std::string Autor;
std::string Editorial;
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

`#include <string>`

and the string is in the `std` namespace. You'll need to use `std::string` rather than `string`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the `string` header and you must either prefix `string` with the namespace `std` or use a `using namespace std;`

```
#ifndef LIBROS_H
#define LIBROS_H

#include <string>
#include "Articulo.h"

class Libros: public Articulo
{
public:
    Libros();
    ~Libros();
    std::string Autor;
    std::string Editorial;
    void mostrar();
    void llenar();
};

# endif
```

Comment: thank you all! my mistake was a include at the father class =S that i miss until i read it all for the third time